# What is meant by "multiple instances of a process"?

Tags: process, operating-system

I have run into the statement "multiple instances of a process". What is meant by a process having a number of instances and how are those created?

Comment: You cannot have multiple instances of a process. You can have multiple instances of an executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process is what is running on your computer. Lets take `notepad.exe`. There is a file on your disk. This file is called executable or process image. When the program is started this process image is loaded from the executable on disk into the memory by the operating system. Next the operating system starts this copy. This running copy is called a process. When multiple copies of an executable are started you have multiple process instances (but still only one executable file on the disk).